# send parameters to actionIndex in Yii controllers

Tags: yii, action, controllers

I want to send a sql string for index action in Yii controller? something for example:

```
index.php?r=staff/index&id=1
```

I tried it and changed actionIndex() to actionIndex($id) but Yii gave me

```
error 400 : Your request is invalid.
```

Is it possible or I have to define another action ?

Comment: The way you describe this, it should work, Yii automatically picks up action parameters from `$_GET` according to the handler function signature. Can you show more code in the controller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

no you don't need to do that, receive the id as the normal request parameter inside your action method

```
public function actionIndex(){

     $id = $_GET['id'];

}
```

Comment: is it secure to use $_GET ?

Answer (score 2):

your can get parameter as follows.

```
        $key = Yii::app()->getRequest()->getParam('your_parameter_name');
```

and also you can get all the parameters from

```
       $allParam = Yii::app()->getRequest()->restParams
```

Answer (score 0):

OR

```
actionIndex($id = 0)
```

in your staff controller